# Angular 5: onSameUrlNavigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In reviewing the changes with the newly released Angular 5 and reading the following blog:  http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/11/02/what-is-new-angular-5/

I noticed the addition of a new flag for the Router options to allow a page to reload.  I had previously had to implement a but of a hack to make this happen.  I was hoping to remove my hack and use this new functionality.  The flag is called onSameUrlNavigation.  However, the Angular compiler complains when I attempt to use it.

My Code:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import Properties               from './../shared/properties';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/' + Properties.ROUTES.catalog.home.route, pathMatch: 'prefix' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class CoreRoutingModule {}
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/core/core-routing.module.ts:13:45
    TS2345: Argument of type '{ onSameUrlNavigation: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtraOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSameUrlNavigation' does not exist in type 'ExtraOptions'.
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Ah really, finally. Should have been in alpha..Sorry can't help though.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this change was removed from 5.0.0 and is now being considered for a future release.   https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19463

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that feature did not make it into v5.0.0 https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19463/
There is a comment in this thread that says it might be considered for v5.1.0

Also if you check out the source files, you can see the `ExtraOptions` interface does not have the `onSameUrlNavigation` property (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.0/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L245). That is what is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

As planned, this feature is part of Angular since v5.1.0
For more information : https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19463